# set background in react js and blur image background

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to set background image and blur image background and with out blur text and login box  so I'm not sure what's wrong here.please help me

```js
     return (
    
        /*  <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authTokens, setAuthTokens: setTokens }} >
           <Router>
        <div >
          <div className="background">
            <div>
              <h1 class="Title">welcome</h1>
            </div>
            {/*  <ul>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/" >Home Page</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/admin" > Admin Page </Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/Signup" component={Signup} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/admin" component={Admin} /> */}
          </div>
        </div>
         {/*  </Router>
        </AuthContext.Provider > */}
      );
    }
```

css

```css
 .background {background-image: url("./img/container.jpg");background-repeat: no-repeat;backgroundsize: 71.5% 100%;background-position: left; position: relative;filter: blur(8px) -webkit-filter: blur(8px);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very much clear. But what I understood is you are trying to blur the background image whenever you are opening login and text box.
If above is your question, then,

You can set z-index to your background's CSS file and login box's CSS file. Then you can add a onClick event on login box's button, such that whenever login box's button is clicked, the background will toggle to blur and login box will be rendered.

For information about z-index: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index